# Trouble adding a border

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm having trouble adding a border to my menu.

If I try border-style:groove; nothing happens but if I do border-top:solid; it appears but only if I do a side and have the border solid?

Its a simple sticky menu that sticks when scrolled.

HTML

```
<div class="menu">
        <ul>
                <li><a href="#">About Me</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">My Work</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Experience</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Contact Me</a></li>

            </ul>
```

CSS

```
* {font-family:arial; margin:0px; padding:0;}
.menu {
border-top:groove;
border-color:#FFF;
background-color:#000;
font-size:30px;
color:#000;
height:50px;
line-height:30px;
width:100%;
text-align:center;
}
.content {margin-top:10px;}
.menu-padding {padding-top:40px;}
.content p {margin-bottom:20px;}
.sticky {position:fixed; top:0;}
ul{border-style:double;}
li{ display:inline-block; }
```

JQuery

```
 $(document).ready(function(){

var menu = document.querySelector('.menu');
var origOffsetY = menu.offsetTop;

function scroll () {
if ($(window).scrollTop() >= origOffsetY) {
$('.menu').addClass('sticky');
$('.content').addClass('menu-padding');
} else {
$('.menu').removeClass('sticky');
$('.content').removeClass('menu-padding');
}  


}

document.onscroll = scroll;
```

Comment: What sides are you wanting the border on?

Comment: all sides, doesnt matter, sorted it now, thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this, use the border shorthand

```
border-top:3px groove #fff;
```

http://jsfiddle.net/SMxp9/ fiddle with your code, and top border on menu.